# Load parts of models weights from previously saved hdf5 file

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, h5py

Hi I have a model I would like to use transfer learning on. I have another model which I have trained and saved its weights. What I would like to do is load the first few weights from the previously trained model to this new model which has the same layers but I have added more layers at the end. How can I load the weights from the first few layers into my new model?

Here is what I have tried:

```
def load_custom_weights(model, data, layer_indices):
  weights = [data[p] for p in layer_indices]
  print(model.weights)
  model.set_weights(weights)
  print(model.get_weights())
  return model

filename = 'unimodal_weights/best_weight_image_only_k-fold_1.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
img_data = f['model_weights']['Image_Branch']['Image_Branch_2']

img = get_img_branch()
img = load_custom_weights(img, img_data, list(img_data))
```

The model seems to load the weights but my accuracy is very low even though the model we are taking the weights from scored well.

Is there a way I can check my model has actually loaded the weights?

**Edit**: They are both multi-GPU models

EDIT 2:

So my model is a bit tricky, I have a sequential model embedded within my model. I want to load the weights to one of the branches specifically the image branch

Here is what my model looks like:

Image_Branch:

```
def get_img_branch():
    Image_Branch = Sequential(name='Image_Branch')
    #block 1
    Image_Branch.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='valid', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='block1_conv1'))
    Image_Branch.add(BatchNormalization())
    Image_Branch.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='valid', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='block1_conv2'))
    Image_Branch.add(BatchNormalization())
    Image_Branch.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool'))
...SNIP...
    #Flatten
    Image_Branch.add(Flatten())
    return Image_Branch
```

Encapsulating model

```
image_input = Input(shape, name='image_input')
#get branches
img = get_img_branch()
#set up our image branch
image_branch = (img)(image_input)
...SNIP
```

we can see that we have taken the image branch which is a sequential model, and have inserted it into a new model. The key here is that in the HDF5 format there is a key called: ['model_weights'] Within this dictionary there is another key called ['Image_Branch'] which corresponds to my model.

What we do is just call:

```
load_weights(img_loc, by_name=True)
```

instead of:

```
img = get_img_branch()
img.load_weights(img_loc, by_name=True)
```

because doing the latter will try to find the image branch key ['Image_Branch'] but wont find it because when we loaded the image branch in the latter example it is the image branch. The layer called "Image_Branch" only exists in the model which encapsulates it.

Also if you want to load a multi-gpu model and inset the weights you would do:

```
model.layers[-2].load_weights(img_loc, by_name=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by naming your layers carefully and using the existing `model.load_weights(filename, by_name=True)`, from the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/):

> `model.load_weights(filepath, by_name=False)` loads the weights of the model from a HDF5 file (created by save_weights). By default, the architecture is expected to be unchanged. To load weights into a different architecture (with some layers in common), use `by_name=True` to load only those layers with the same name.

What the name refers to is for example `Dense(21, ..., name='dense_layer_1')` or your `Image_Branch` submodel. So check the original names of the layers, and then recreate the new model with the matching names while the new layers have distinct new names.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although one needs to tweak it a bit when one is using a nested model.